# wlServerContext value coming '/' after building the environment file from ant script

Tags: ant, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

I built my project by using ["build-app"](http://pastebin.com/3bdjiu9Z) ant task. After build is finished I noticed that value of `wlServerContext` attribute in `"wlclient.properties"` and `"worklight.plist"` is coming `'/'` instead of `'/MyProject/'.` If I build my project from eclipse then everything is coming just fine. I am using `Worklight 6.2` Consumer Edition.

Comment: Prerak, when you ask a question about Worklight, **always** mention your Worklight version and build number. There are many versions of Worklight out there.

Comment: @IdanAdar I've update the question. I am using worklight version 6.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the worklightserverhost attribute, you must include the project name which will be your context root.
Try this:
worklightserverhost="${wl.server.protocol}://${wl.server.ip}:${wl.server.port}/${wl.runtime.name}"